# Stability of the op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bode-plot, frequency-response, unity-gain

I am confused if the below amplifier will be stable or not when it acts as unity gain amplifier (
with a feedback factor of 1) ?

My analysis: PM = zero from the bode plot , so the system is stable ! If we use a feedback factor 1, then the system will still remain stable ???

Please correct me If I am wrong !!

[image]

Comment: "PM"?  I assume that's "phase, something that starts with M", but it's not clear.

Comment: Its Phase Margin

Comment: Fot PM=zero the closed-loop system is at its stability limit (oscillation condition).

Comment: A better question is find the 0 dB line and gain at PM = 45’

Answer (score 1):

If that were the open-loop gain/phase of a real amplifier, then with unity-gain feedback the closed-loop system would be metastable, with a pole pair right on the imaginary axis.

If that were the published gain/phase, I'd assume that the thing would oscillate in practice, or at least couldn't be trusted not to.

It certainly wouldn't be a useful amplifier in any case.  Such an amplifier, if it were stable at all, would ring indefinitely, and have 100% overshoot.  Typically you want to design for a phase margin of 60 degrees or more; 45 degrees is where you'll start seeing ringing and overshoot.  You might go to 30 degrees if you're absolutely desperate.